# Modify MySQL foreign key related column without dropping foreign key relation

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, alter-table

I need to modify a foreign key related column. When I tried to alter it I got "Error on rename of 'x' to 'y' (errno: 150)" error. So I googled and found foreign key relation is the 'villain'. I dropped the foreign key relation, altered the column and created foreign key relation.

Is there any way to alter foreign key related columns without dropping the relation?

Comment: I believe MySQL does not support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah i think you have a SQL command like :

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

which should be session based. Then you set =1 once you're done.

Comment: `foreign_key_checks` is a global (only) server variable.

Comment: `foreign_key_checks` is both global and session, so the example will work and will only impact the current session.  `mysqldump` writes these repeatedly to backup files so foreign key constraints don't interfere with restoration.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot My mistake, I was reading the wrong row.

Comment: But I still don't get how this will help renaming the column.

Comment: From what I understood Praveen wants to do some work on a column that has a foreign key constraint, and that without actually dropping the constraint; but maybe I got this wrong ?

Comment: @ypercube : Actually I dont want to rename the columns, but to change data types.